# setting the x and y points of a label through an animation in xcode

Tags: objective-c, animation, ios7.1, cgrect, xcode5.1

I am fading in a label and I am attempting to have it come in from the side of the view. I am using this code to fade it in:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [label setAlpha:1.0];
    [label setFrame:CGRectMake(10,20,100,200)];
```

In the story board I have the X axis as -52 and I am trying to have it change to 10 in the 1.0 second animation. The fading part is working fine but I can't figure out how to change the x or y axis through the animation. I have tried a lot of different things but nothing is working. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Are you actually committing the animations? `[UIView commitAnimations];`

Comment: Yes, I do have that line I just did not copy it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use frame property to set the x and y. Do not change the width/height.

```
 [label setFrame:CGRectMake(10,20,label.frame.size.width,label.frame.size.height)];
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have shown does not actually show committing the animations. You should use the more modern block based animations that prevents this from happening

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                 animations:^{
                   label.alpha = 1.f;

                   CGRect frame = label.frame;
                   frame.origin = CGPointMake(10.f, 20.f);
                   label.frame = frame;
                 }];
```